# Is Magento1.9.4 is compatible on PHP 5.10.1?

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

I am trying to install magento on server from last 2 weeks.
My PHP version is 5.10.1
My Magento Version is 1.9.24
Continously it gives error "[an error occurred while processing this directive]"
I changed permission also.
Please help me to get it out from this situation. I am tired now.

Comment: Have u check log files

Comment: yes i checked, but not solved yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean PHP 5.5.10, which is indeed compatible with Magento 1.9.

Make sure that that you have set all file system permissions properly, the official Magento documentation explains this thoroughly:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html#privs-after

If this does not work, check the Apache and PHP logs for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved now.

1. I rename `php.ini.sample` to `php.ini`.
2. I change permission 644 of this files:

   `.htaccess, index.php, php.ini.`